# Flutter screen(list) is reloading after coming back from another screen(detail)

Tags: flutter

I have created a Flutter application with a list. On tap of an item, I am opening detail of that item.

The problem is whenever I come back from the detail screen, the list screen is reloaded. I don't want to reload the list every time.

I have used BloC architecture in this.

Below are the code snippets. Please suggest.

Thank You.

**Main**

```
    void main() {

  final userRepository = UserRepository();
  ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient(httpClient: http.Client());

  runApp(BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
    builder: (context) {
      return AuthenticationBloc(
          userRepository: userRepository, apiClient: apiClient)
        ..dispatch(AppStarted());
    },
    child: MyApp(userRepository: userRepository),
      ));
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  final UserRepository userRepository;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.userRepository}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        bloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context),
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationUninitialized) {
            return SplashPage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            return HomePage(userRepository: userRepository);
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage(userRepository: userRepository);
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }

          return null;
        },
      ),
        );
       }
     }
```

**List Screen**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
UserRepository userRepository;

HomePage({@required this.userRepository}) : super();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient(httpClient: http.Client());

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Home'),
  ),
  drawer: AppDrawer(userRepository),
  body: BlocProvider(
    builder: (context) {
      return HomeBloc(apiClient);
    },
    child: _HomeContent(),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
    ),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeContent extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final HomeBloc homeBloc = BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context);

homeBloc.dispatch(FetchMovieList());

return BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is MovieListLoading) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    if (state is MovieListLoaded) {
      List<Movie> topRatedMovies = state.movieList;

      return new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: Card(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(ApiClient.IMAGE_BASE_URL +
                      topRatedMovies[index].poster_path),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(topRatedMovies[index].title),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              _onListItemTapped(topRatedMovies[index].id, context);
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: topRatedMovies.length,
      );
    }

    if (state is MovieListError) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Error in calling API'),
      );
    }

    return Center(child: Text('Employee data not found'));
      },
   );
   }


   void _onListItemTapped(int movieId, BuildContext context) {
       Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MovieDetailPage(
              movieId: movieId,
            )));
       }
     }
```

Comment: `"I don't want to reload the list every time."` - this is how the things work: `build()` method is always called,   you cannot avoid that

Comment: Oh Okay. I was thinking that we can control it like native Android. Thanks for reply @pskink

Answer (score 0):

At anytime your build method needs to be ready for multiple build calls. If build calls are causing problem then something is probably wrong. It would be a better idea to fetch the data outside the build method to prevent unnecessary API calls.

For example you can create a **Stateful Widget** and in **initState** method you can fetch the data. After that, build method is called to prepare UI with the data. You can use a Future Builder to show progress and update UI when the data is fetched.

Example:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future _future;

  Future getData() async {
    // Fetch data
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            default:
              if (snapshot.data.hasErrors) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.data.errors}');
              } else {
                // Data is fetched, build UI
                return ListTile();
              }
          }
        });
  }
}
```